# Onsen UI　を使用したソースをAndroidのChrome（「PC版サイトを見る」のチェックを外した状態）で動す方法につきまして。

Tags: onsen-ui

Onsen UIを使用して、ハイブリッドとWebアプリ（ブラウザを利用したアプリ）の開発を行うことを検討しております。

Monacaで用意されているテンプレート(Sliding Menu)のソースを、Nodeのサーバーに置いて、AndroidのChromeで動かしてみたところ、「PC版サイトを見る」のチェックを外したモードでは上手く動きませんでした。（真っ白い画面になりました）

こちら回避する方法はございますでしょうか。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Developer Toolでエラー内容が確認できそうな気がします。一度ご確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

すみません、AndroidのChromeでDeveloper Toolを使用するのに手間取りました。
（Windows端末だとなぜか認識してくれなく、Macでやっと認識してDeveloper Toolで確認できました。）

loader.js内の15行目で使用しているsplitでエラーになっておりました。
（エラー内容：「Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined」）

そのため、onsenui.min.jsなどのjsファイルが読み込めてないようでしたので
試しにindex.htmlの方で直接jsファイルを指定するようにしたところ、ひとまず動くようになりました。

なぜ該当箇所でエラーになっているかまでは、今の所把握はできておりません。
もし前例や回避策がありそうでしたらご教授いただければ幸いでございます。
（無さそうでしたら今回は直接jsファイルを指定する方式で進めたいと思っております。）

[image: エラー箇所]